# Jquery toggle() follow border on navbar bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Jquery toggle() function that is linked to the navbar. When the user clicks the toggle button, it displays new content under the navbar. I have applied a border-bottom to the navbar and the toggle class. I would like this border to follow the toggle as it expands. Is this possible?

I have made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jFVBwx4Lcj) to explain my point further.

Below is my Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$banner = $(".banner");
$banner.hide();
$(".show-banner").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".banner").is(":hidden")) {


               $("nav.navbar.navbar-inverse").attr('style', 'border-bottom: border-bottom:4px solid #ff0000;!important').delay( 5000 );

            } else {
                    $("nav.navbar.navbar-inverse").attr('style', 'border-bottom: border-bottom:4px solid #ff0000; !important').delay( 5000 );

            }
   $banner.slideToggle()

    $(".navbar-collapse.collapse").addClass("hide-all");


});

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `slideToggle()` method you can place another function to perform an action at the completion of the animation.  New [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ad5xGugngm).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $banner = $(".banner");
    $banner.hide();
    $(".show-banner").on("click", function() {
      $("nav.navbar.navbar-inverse").attr('style', 'border-bottom: 4px solid #000 !important';).delay( 5000 );

      $banner.slideToggle(function(){
        if ($(".banner").is(":hidden")) {
          $("nav.navbar.navbar-inverse").attr('style', 'border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000 !important;').delay( 5000 );
        }
      });

      $(".navbar-collapse.collapse").addClass("hide-all");

    });

  });
```

So what I'm doing is on click of the toggle button, immediately turn the original border of the navbar black as the banner animates out with the red border. If the banner is being closed, then restore the original border to red upon completion of closing.

There are probably other ways to do this but I think this accomplishes what you're after.

Comment: oops.  any idea why?

Comment: No idea man something is overriding it and i cant see what it is xD could you spare 2 mins? Thanks man appreciate it

Comment: i just noticed something, but have no idea if this could be the problem... `!important` should go before the semicolon.